# Gunicorn Flask app does not doing system commands

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn, python-venv

This is my code`

```
 @app.route('/social_add/<us_id>/<us_phone>/<us_birth>/<us_gen>', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
    def social_add(us_id, us_phone, us_birth, us_gen):
        os.system("sudo chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image")
        os.system("mkdir /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image/" + us_id)
        os.system("sudo chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image/" + us_id)
```

This is error`

```
gunicorn[119261]: sh: 1: sudo: not found
gunicorn[119261]: sh: 1: mkdir: not found
gunicorn[119261]: sh: 1: sudo: not found
```

I tried this program`

```
subprocess.Popen("sudo chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image", shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("mkdir /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image/" + us_id, shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("sudo chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image/" + us_id, shell=True)
```

But the error is the same

Comment: Have you tried using `subprocess.run` as an alternative? [SubProcess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html)

Comment: I have already found solution os.mdkri(filename, mode=0o777)

Comment: Add an Answer to the question then

Answer (score 0):

```
os.mkdir(filename, mode=0o777)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation

Comment: `mdkri` or `mkdir`?

Answer (score 0):

There is a big warning block in the documentation at https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor to use the full path to the executeable and that you can use  `shutil.which()` to find it.

so basicly

```
subprocess.Popen("sudo /bin/chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image", shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("/bin/mkdir /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image/" + us_id, shell=True)
subprocess.Popen("sudo /bin/chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image/" + us_id, shell=True)
```

Not sure about the sudo though ....
Just found this out because i had a similar problem with gunicorn/django and subprocess.run(). (Also using run() does not fix it :))

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to this.  Add a `PATH` export statement before your command, like so:

```
subprocess.Popen("export PATH=$PATH:/bin; chmod 777 /home/gor/tarber/static/user_image")
```

It is important to note that this export only survives the one `subprocess.Popen` command, so it needs to be repeated each time.  While this may seem worse than adding `/bin/` to the `chmod` statement, it has the advantage of saving the path for any processes you call within the command, i.e. a bash script.  You could also concatenate multiple commands in the same `subprocess.Popen` statement.